# how to prevent the difference in AudioContext.decodeAudioData under chrome/FF

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, audio

i'm using wavesurfer.js for a tool i wrote. I used it to display a certain mp3 file. The problem i have is that if i load the mp3 file in both browsers the one in chrome gets chopped off in the beginning. I started debugging the problem and it seems that a call to audioContext.decodeAudioData from the AudioAPI results in the mp3 getting chopped off in chrome, the input in both cases is consistent (a 2781 bytearray goes in).

From firefox I get 121248 samples back and the layout looks good, from chrome I get 114330 and it's chopped off in the beginning.

I tested another file which is longer and it also gave me a difference of 6918 samples missing.

The same problem occurred under linux with FF where the samples returned are 124416. (gstreamer plugin)

(btw these are all comparable since the systems all use 48kHz output)

The plugin to decode mp3 under windows for firefox is the vlc plugin since ff itself is not capable to decode mp3 due to licensing issues.

the file is encoded as:
Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III,  v2.5,  24 kbps, 8 kHz, Monaural

originally it was a PCM 32kHz mono file

I can imagine that mp3 is not sample consistent due to different implementations of the decoders. (kinda answered my own question here)

What would be a consistent codec over multiple browsers that produces sampleconsistency? I know that Wav should produce comparable results, right?
How about ogg? can I assume consistency in the amount of samples since the codebase should be the same, or does these differences in samples stem from the fact that the audioAPI is built up differently in the different browsers (a bit counter intuitive from an API i would say)